# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefrompng() in pathStack trace: #0 {main} thrown in path on line 3

Tags: php, html, gd

Again! this question might be similar but they don't work for me. I just have this code:

```
$jj = imagecreatefrompng("certified.png");
```

It is like I have a computer from some other world. The GD is enabled, I have restarted the server but nope this does'not works.

*And gd functions work with no other. Might look like other question but its not.
Can someone please help me!!!

Comment: Okay! So some how it works on a Real Server that is Live